# How to add another column to the issues table report in Redmine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I would like to know if someone can help me to determine what steps I do need to modify Redmine in the table shown at the URL:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/projects/my_project/issues
```

I need to add another column, lets say "close date", where it reports the last date on which an issue became closed state.

As I understand Redmine, the matter is to return the field created _ on of the journal whose journal _ details change to status _ id = 5

And the change would be somewhere in issues_controller, but given my ignorance on Ruby and Ruby on Rails I feel lost...

So, any help would be very valuable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think there is a setting in RedMine to add a custom field to issues, projects, users, etc.

Go to `Administration => Custom Fields => Select Issue Tab => New Custom Field`.

Hope it helps. =)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to handle ruby code for to customize issue table.

Login as admin and select

Administration (top left corner) -> Settings-> Issue tracking

in the bottom of selected page you can see the table

**Default columns displayed on the issue list**

Select the fields that you need inside you project.

If you need of "new fields" to be searchable or used as filter :

Administration (top left corner) -> Custom fields -> Issue

Create your field and select option that you need.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields

Comment: The other answer is worse, this one more precisely answers the question.